# Resetting default fan settings (smcFanControl)

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, fan

I'm currently the process of fixing a friends Mac, they have smcFanControl installed, how do I go about resetting the mac back to it's default settings and get rid of what ever control smcFanControl had over the machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

smcFanControl just offers the ability to set the minimum fan speed. If you drag the sliders in smcFanControl all the way to the left (minimum values) these are the defaults for the computer. You can then quit smcFanControl. The SMC will automatically turn up the fans as need be - smcFanControl just allows users to specify a higher minimum speed if they find heat to be an issue.

Comment: so If I just reset it back to the minimum values, quit the application and then delete it the SMC will take back control?

Comment: Yes / No. Yes the SMC will take care of the fans but no, the SMC never stopped controlling the fans. SmcFanControl just sets a minimum speed. The SMC still speeds up or slows down the fan as need be down to the minimum.